# How to create a discount card for Apple Wallet?

Tags: ios, applepay, wallet

How can I create (and is it possible at all) discount cards for a coffee shop using Apple Wallet and iOS APIs?

The effect I want to get is the following: iOS users should have a personal card in Apple Wallet which they will bring to the coffee shop. In the coffee shop there will be a scanner which can add score for each scan and nullify it when the score reaches let's say 7 scans (so users will have each 7-th cup of coffee for free).

Comment: You can add a pass to the wallet that displays a barcode; search for information on Passkit.  You will need your backend server to track the user's "balance" and update it each time they scan. You can also use a (much less secure) method where the coffee shop displays a QR code that the user scans with your app to update their balance; the problem is they can easily take a photo of the QR code and scan when they aren't in the shop.

Comment: @Paulw11 I had no experience working with barcode scanners. Can you give a high-level explanation on how the scanner will pass info to my server? I guess, in my use case there should be at least 3 options of scan: 1) Check the current balance; 2) Add bonus point(s); 3) Substract bonus points if the user has enough of them for free coffee.

Comment: The scanner would be connected to a computer. Typically they act like a keyboard and simply type the data in to software running on the computer. A coffee show I used to go to had a tablet on the counter running an app. The app scanned receipt barcode from your phone using the tablet camera and uploaded the data to the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a Apple Wallet pass is described here: [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/YourFirst.html)
You edit the `pass.json` describing your pass, then you can sign it using Apples `signpass` tool after you have registered a pass type identifier and found your Team ID. If you want to update the pass to display the information to customers, you would need a server that implements the [web service API](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html).

As Paulw11 has said, you will need some sort of scanner to read the data from customers passes. One way is QR codes, in which your cashier will hold a camera to the QR code on the pass to read the customer info, usually it will just be a unique ID which you have mapped to a customer account. Another possibility is using NFC so the customer taps their phone to a NFC reader which will transmit their unique ID for you to process.

If you would like to try reading passes using NFC, see [PassNinja](http://passninja.com/).
Here is a video of it in action: 
[NFC Pass Solution for Mobile Wallets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7C9O7zpn4ZE)

Disclosure: I work for [Flomio](https://flomio.com/), the company behind PassNinja.